# Sort bibliography by Authors surname and then by year?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I would like to sort my reference list by Author surname and then year of publication.

Here's the code I used.

```
\usepackage[%
  backend=bibtex      % biber or bibtex
,style=authoryear    % Alphabeticalsch
%,style=numeric-comp  % numerical-compressed
 ,sorting=none        % no sorting
 ,sortcites=true      % some other example options ...
 ,bibencoding=ascii
 ,block=none
 ,indexing=false
 ,citereset=none
 ,isbn=true
 ,url=true
 ,doi=true            % prints doi
 ,natbib=true         % if you need natbib functions
]{biblatex}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `\newrefcontext[sorting=nyt]` before `\printbibliography` e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\newrefcontext[sorting=nyt]
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```